# Standard connectors moving to premium. Is Logic Apps also affected

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, powerapps

[This link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Standard-connectors-moving-to-premium/td-p/382248) lists connectors moving from standard to premium in Flow and Powerapps.
Will they also move to premium for logic apps which are Azure rather than Office365 based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your concern about the connectors moving from standard to premium in logic app, I think you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). The azure support team can provide you a professional answer.